# Dropbear -> Openssh: Why does it ask for a password now?

Tags: ssh, embedded, openssh, yocto, dropbear

I'm working on an embedded board (i.MX6) with a Yocto-based embedded Linux. So far I used Dropbear as SSH server. However, Dropbear doesn't provide an SFTP server, which I need. Therefore I switched from Dropbear to OpenSSH (built it from the standard Poky sources, and installed it via opkg).

However, since then I cannot login to the board via SSH anymore, because the server asks for a password, which I don't know. The only user is root, and it has no password configured (this is still true, because I can log in locally via RS232 without problems). Why does OpenSSH ask for a password? How can I remove that?

I thought that maybe there's a passphrase set in one of the private keys in `/etc/ssh`:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

So I did `ssh-keygen -p -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` respectively for each of them, but it didn't help.

This is the essential pieces of the sshd_config file:

```
# grep '^[^#]' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Protocol 2
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox # Default for new installations.
Compression no
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 4
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you have `debug-tweaks` in your `IMAGE_FEATURES` or `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES`?

If so, the `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` should include `ssh_allow_empty_password();` which in turns should set `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config_readonly`. That should allow you to use empty passwords with OpenSSH.

Comment: Yes, I do have `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks"` in my conf/local.conf. But something else may have gone wrong with the installation, because `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` was not set. I set it now manually in both config files, and now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, good!
Could you try to force a re-generation of your image by running `bitbake -C rootfs <image-name>` and verify whether it works then? If it still doesn't work, something strange is going on.

Comment: Well, the thing is, that OpenSSH is not part of the base image, and hence it's also not included in the rootfs. I need it only for development purpose (because I temporarily need SFTP), so I just built it as an individual ipk package with bitbake and installed it with opkg.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. `debug-tweaks` in  `IMAGE_FEATURES` does only influence the image creation step, and not individual packages.

Comment: I think `debug-tweaks` will remove password from console only.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "debug-tweaks" in your `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` then the password will be blank: this may be ok for development images.

If you want to have some security instead, you can either add a recipe that installs a public key to */root/.ssh/authorized_keys* or use the [extrausers](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.7/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-extrausers) class in an image recipe or local configuration to set the password.

Comment: Yes, I do have `debug-tweaks` set. It's only development stage, so no security is needed (or wanted) yet. Still, I don't understand why `ssh` asks me for a password. And what that password is...

Comment: I recommend having some level of security right up front.  If it's baked in from the beginning, you won't have a hole you have to plug before the product ships.